# Create string from multiple clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a list that looks like this:

```
<ul class="clearfix alignleft">
   <li id="cat-1"><a href="#All">All</a></li>
    <li id="cat-5"><a href="#Mobile">Mobile</a></li>
    <li id="cat-4"><a href="#Webdesign">Webdesign</a></li>
</ul>
```

So when the user clicks on `mobile`, I take the attribute href, and slice the `'#'` but after that when the user clicks on `webdesign` let's say I need to create a string like `.Mobile,.Webdesign`and so on..so I have to add to the string.... when the user clicks on an anchor I add a class of `.clicked`

Doesn anyone if this is possibile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like below,

**Markup**

```
<ul class="clearfix alignleft" id="trackClick"> <!-- added trackClick -->
   <li id="cat-1"><a href="#All">All</a></li>
    <li id="cat-5"><a href="#Mobile">Mobile</a></li>
    <li id="cat-4"><a href="#Webdesign">Webdesign</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
var tracker = [];
$('#trackClick').find('a').click( function () {
   tracker.push($(this).attr('href').replace('#', '.')); 
   //or tracker.push('.' + $(this).attr('href').substring(1));
});

console.log(tracker); // will print clicked href .Mobile,.Webdesign
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/B8AWf/)

Comment: `this.href` is more efficient than `$(this).attr('href')`

Comment: @pomeh `this.href` will return you the complete URL, so you need to use `$(this).attr('href')` if you want to get what is inside href attribute. or use `.getAttribute(`

Comment: Yes you're right, sorry about that. So then `this.getAttribute('href')` would be more efficient, right ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var classStr = '';
$('ul a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  classStr += (classStr.length > 0 ? ', ' : '') + this.href.replace('#', '.');
});
```

You can put it in an array also @vega shows:

```
var classStr = [];
$('ul a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // $.unique() to make sure that no multiple instance of href
  $.unique(classStr.push(this.href.replace('#', '.'))); 
});
console.log(classStr.join(', '));
```